# ezPublish: Unknown template variable 'view_parameters' in namespace in design/dffestival/templates/page_footer.tpl

Tags: php, ezpublish

We have received below errors on the home page:

```
eZTemplate @ design/dffestival/templates/page_footer.tpl:8[6]:
Unknown template variable 'view_parameters' in namespace ''
```

In our `pagefooter.tpl` file have below code:

```
<div class="attribute-layout">
  {attribute_view_gui attribute=$footerNode.data_map.layout view_parameters=$view_parameters}
</div>
```

We are using `eZ Publish Community Project 2012.6` version.

Could anyone explain why I can't retrieve the `view_parameters` variable and how to do retrieve it?

Thanks

Sunil

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u should start here:
http://www.ezpedia.org/ez/view_parameters

> Remember view parameters are by default available only within the
>   context of the content module and it's views.
>
> All other modules (by default) do not support this feature.
>
> The recommended alternative to view parameters in these situations
>   would be using get / post parameters instead.

Or here:
https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Templates/Basic-template-tasks/Custom-view-parameters

> In some cases $view_parameters won't work, try
>   $module_result.view_parameters there. So the example above will be:
>   The color is: {$module_result.view_parameters.color} 
>  The amount
>   is: {$module_result.view_parameters.amount}

Or here (check "$module_result section"):
https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/3.10/Templates/The-pagelayout/Variables-in-pagelayout

Comment: Thanks for your reply it's works for me.

We are using: https://doc.ez.no/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Templates/Basic-template-tasks/Custom-view-parameters

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer :**

You are trying to retrieve the `$view_parameters` within the pagelayout (or a template included in it). This is not possible by design and this is completely normal.

**Long answer :**

View parameters are meant to be used from the views/templates which are used by the content module : for instance, when viewing a content from its alias URL or using its system URL like `/content/view/full/2`.

They are useful if you want to pass some parameters from the URL to the content view and they are taken into account by the cache system which is a very important thing to keep in mind (**this is not the case when using "vanilla" GET parameters**).

The main usage is for pagination, for instance : `/content/view/full/2/(offest)/2/(limit)10`

One of the best practices when developing with eZ Publish (legacy) is to ask yourself : why do you need to retrieve these parameters into your layout ? I guess that you want to control your global layout using them and this is not a good idea.

If you want to control the layout based on something which depends on the content, then I'll suggest to use persistent variables. You will basically use the `ezpagedata_set` operator in the content/view template and retrieve this value in your pagelayout with `ezpagedata()` | see https://doc.ez.no/doc_hidden/eZ-Publish/Technical-manual/4.x/Reference/Template-operators/Miscellaneous/ezpagedata_set

Last but not least, remember that the module result is computed before the pagelayout (simply because the pagelayout will include this result using `$module_result.content`).